# SCDF UI doesnt override the properties either in the property or in argument section

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

SCDF UI Pulls the configuration for the properties from consul, i need to override consul configuration for one of the property, but it doesnt override the properties with app.taskname.propertykeyname=value either in the property section or in argument section.
Any suggestion to implement this?

Taskname is springboot
For example my property in consul is
springboot.uk.jobRundate= Empty

So i would like to override this property in SCDF UI
Property section:
key                         value
springboot.uk.jobRundate     01-Jan-23
Arguments as
app.springboot.springboot.uk.jobRundate=01-Jan-23

Either of these is override in SCDF UI, instead it takes today's date

Comment: Which version of SCDF? What is your platform type being used? Local, K8S or CF?
How you know which properties are / env are sent to the task?
Can you create a simple reproduce project with the shell commands to use and null task app?